# How do you do a count query in php with a where clause?

Tags: php, count

So I have this query like this

```
$sql2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE YourUsername = '$MyUsername' AND PostId = '$PostId'";


if ($result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
  echo $rowcount;


 }
```

and I have 2 rows in my database which meet the clause requirements but for some reason it keeps outputting 1 as the result. How do I make it display the actual count and not just 1 when in reality the count is 2 and so on for future rows.

Comment: What you posted looks fine, so the problem is probably in how you have defined `$sql2`.  It should be something like `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM my_database"`

Comment: i edited, for some reason it cut out part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're SELECTing the count of the rows in your first line, so when the query is run, it's returning the row count into **$result2**.  You don't need to use **mysqli_num_rows**.

Foul

Comment: such a simple fix and I for some reason didn't understand it because when looking it up everyone kept using num_rows